# Unix sh Script confusion

Tags: bash, unix

I have a script one of my Professors from college gave us to modify however I cannot seem to figure out exactly what it does. Can anyone help me to understand it a bit better?

```
for i 
do grep look $i; done
```

From what I can gather it greps the value of the variable i, which could be a file or directory. However I am not familiar with how the look command comes into play. I would greatly appreciate any tips you could offer.

Comment: It might help if you told us what this is supposed to do; the syntax looks novel to me (as it appears to be missing an `in`).

Comment: Is that the whole thing?

Comment: yes, that is all he gave us, and he didn't tell us what it does. When I run it with a file or directory name it runs, but returns nothing.

Comment: Look isn't a command in the example as given, ie grep look $i => grep for 'look' in $i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`look` isn't a command, it's the first parameter to [`grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep). So it will search for the word `look` in the file named `$i`. (`grep` will not search folders unless you pass in `-R` as in `grep -R look $i`.)

The confusing bit is that `for i` usually comes with an `in WORDS` specified, so `for i in one two three` will run the commands between `do` and `done` three times: once with variable `i` = "one", once with `i` = "two", and once with `i` = "three". However, the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs) explains what to do if `in` isn't specified:

> If ‘in words’ is not present, the for command executes the commands once for each positional parameter that is set, as if ‘in "$@"’ had been specified [...].

So, in short, if your script is in a file named `foo.sh`, then calling `foo.sh file1 file2` will look for the word `look` in files "file1" and "file2".